# Separation Properties of the Radial Plane Topology

Tags: general-topology, separation-axioms

I am asked to prove or disprove that the Radial Plane is regular, completely regular and normal; using the following definition of its topology:

> A set $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$ is radially open if for every $x\in A$ we have that $A$ contains an open segment through $x$ in any direction.

If I am not mistaken I can prove that it is completely regular similarly to the Moore Plane (showing that for any open neighbourhood and a point $x$ in it I can found another neighbourhood whose closure is contained in the first one) using the segments through $x$, and because it is also $T_1$ then it would also be regular.

But I am struggling to find if it's normal or not. At first I thought about taking the sets $K = \{ (x,y) \ : \ x^2+y^2=1 \} \setminus \{(0,1)\}$ and $L = \{(0,1)\}$ but I am not that sure that $K$ is closed and even if it is I am not sure those two can't be separated by radially open sets. Any help? Thanks in advance

Comment: I am not sure whether this space is normal but your proposed counter example doesn't work.  It is easy to show that $K$ is closed and moreover $K$ may be separated from $L$ by open sets $U$ and $V$: take a ball $B_1$, of radius less than 1, tangent to the unit ball at $(0,1)$ and another ball  $B_2$, of radius bigger than 1, also tangent to the unit ball at $(0,1)$.  Then take $U$ to be the exterior of $B_1$ intercepted with the interior of $B_2$, while $V$ is the interior of $B_1$, joined with the exterior of $B_2$, joined with $(0,1)$.

Comment: Here is a counter example that works: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3493471/separating-sets-in-the-radial-plane-topology